# Unsure how to avoid the following type error: found: Any required: String

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is what my data looks like:

```
configStr: String =
"
{
  "validation": {
    "target_feed": "tables.validation",
    "data_validations":
        [
            {"program": "program1",
            "test_description": "Checking if column1 are distinct",
            "input_column": "column1",
            "test": "distinctness",
            "query": "select * from table1",
            "condition": "None"},
            {"program": "program12",
            "test_description": "Checking if column2 are distinct",
            "input_column": "column2",
            "test": "Anomaly",
            "query": "select * from table2",
            "condition": "None"}
        ]
  }
}"
```

I need to iterate through the data validations and leverage each of those fields. I'm planning to do that like this:

```
val resultsAsDf = conf("test")
.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("data_validations")
.asInstanceOf[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]
.map{ dv => someFunc(dv) }
.reduce(_.unionAll(_))
```

Now, to create `someFunc` that will handle the logic. I build something like this:

```
def someFunc(testCase: Map[String, Any]): Unit = {

    if (testCase("test") == "distinctness") {
        
        val tempDF = spark.sql(testCase("query"))
        
        val verificationResults: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
        .onData(tempDF)                                                    
        .addCheck(
        Check(CheckLevel.Error, testCase("program"))
        .hasDistinctness(testCase("column"), Check.IsOne))
        .run()
        }                                                           
    }
    else{
        println("Nothing")
    }
}
```

Now, I get the following errors:

```
<console>:54: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: String
               val tempDF = spark.sql(testCase("query"))
                                              ^
<console>:60: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: String
               Check(CheckLevel.Error, testCase("program"))
```

The thing is, I need the mapped values to be various types which is why I chose `Any`. Is there any way around this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SequenceToSequence, who is almost correct by the way, mixed up which type needs to change. `testCase` is returning `Any`, when `spark.sql(_)` expects a `String`, the problem isn't the return of the `someFunc` it's the return of the `Map`.

```scala
def someFunc(testCase: Map[String, Any]): Unit = {}
```

```scala
val tempDF = spark.sql(testCase("query"))
```

```scala
// Spark 3.1.1 ScalaDoc
def sql(sqlText: String): DataFrame
```

So when you pass your `String` key into the map, you get an `Any`, which is not a `String` as `spark.sql` expects:

```scala
testCase: Map[String, Any]

testCase("string") // Result Any
```

Reference documentation:
[SparkSession ScalaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html)

Answer (score -2):

Your someFunc returns Unit, which is similar to java's 'void' type, however, spark.sql requires a String. You will need to modify your testCase to return a string that contains a query.

```
def someFunc(testCase: Map[String, Any]): String = { ... }
```

Comment: It's the return of the `Map`, not the function. `spark.sql` expects a `String`, which is provided by looking up the key in the `Map`, but the map returns `Any` instead of `String`